# nasty process hogging my shell

Tags: linux, bash

While for most of the processes started from shell I can grab my shell back from them with a sequence of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>z</kbd> and `bg`, it seems that some won't allow me back in control in the case of, e.g., `mysqld`.

How can I convince it to let go of my shell's stdin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried "reset" and hitting enter after your shell is gone? You might not see it getting typed, but lots of times you'll get your shell back.

Sometimes it will look like it's not allowing input, but just some strange characters were sent, preventing output.

Comment: that did the trick :)

Answer (score 1):

You are better off starting them with an `&` at the end, which starts the process in the background to begin with. For example, `mysqld &`, though I don't see why you need to manually run it on background, since it should automatically fork itself to background.